# cv_bridge missing reported by rosbuild system

Tags: cv-bridge, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Hi there, I got the below email today from Willow's build server complaining that the cv_bridge package could not be found. AFAIK that package is still in ROS electric.
Any suggestion what I might be doing wrong?
thx, D.

---

devel_electric_bosch_manipulation_utils_lucid_amd64 - Build # 10 - Still Failing:

Check console output at http://build.willowgarage.com//job/devel_electric_bosch_manipulation_utils_lucid_amd64/10/ to view the results.

Result: Build failures:
pr2_interactive_segmentation

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/rosbuild/hudson/workspace/devel_electric_bosch_manipulation_utils_lucid_amd64/test_output/testfailures.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:137)
at groovy.util.CharsetToolkit.(CharsetToolkit.java:68)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.newReader(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:9798)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.getText(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:9222)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$239.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3432)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:57)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:236)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:561)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:536)
at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:123)
   at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:101)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

### Result: Build failures with context:

pr2_interactive_segmentation
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[rosbuild] Building package pr2_interactive_segmentation
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests pr2_interactive_segmentation
[rospack] couldn't find dependency [cv_bridge] of [pr2_interactive_segmentation]
[rospack] missing dependency

CMake Error at /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:125 (message):

Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
'pr2_interactive_segmentation'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:202 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12253/cv_bridge-missing-reported-by-rosbuild-system/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1420 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-02-01**:
I'd suggest that you list the solution as an answer, so that others can find it if they made the same mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turned out that I only forgot the dependency on another stack, Mea culpa.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2011-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0